# epoll_wait and changing system time back

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, epoll

My app uses epoll_wait to perform a timed wait for IO events.  If no event happens, epoll_wait is supposed to return after the timeout and my app continues.

During testing, someone turn the system clock back by a day and the part of my app that uses epoll_wait stopped working for 24 hours. Obviously, this is a problem.

I've rummaged around looking for something that might allow my app to know that the time has changed (for example, a signal) but I haven't found anything.

Is there any way to deal with abrupt time changes like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer based upon a monotonic time (e.g., timer_create(2)) to generate a signal and do a blocking epoll_wait, and check for -1 return code and errno set to EINTR.

Comment: It's strange that the man page on epoll_wait doesn't really specify what clock you wait on when you give it a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/eventpoll.c?v=4.7#L1614) of epoll_wait uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC so it should be immune to system clock changes. (I investigated this since I was seeing a similar problem and wanted to discount epoll_wait as a possible cause.) Before v2.6.37 it used to use jiffies which are also monotonic.

I've submitted a [patch](http://marc.info/?l=linux-man&m=147393200023862) to the epoll_wait man page to clarify this.